# Overrding the Slack channel destination

Tags: node.js, express, slack-api

I have created a slack webhook and integrated to a specific channel but now I want to use this webhook to send to a different channel as you can see here

```
export interface IncomingWebhookDefaultArguments {
    username?: string;
    icon_emoji?: string;
    icon_url?: string;
    channel?: string;   <<-----
    text?: string;
    link_names?: boolean;
    agent?: Agent;
}
```

IncomingWebhookDefaultArguments accept a channel ID to send the specific slack message i want to override it when I am sending a post message to my webhook URL but I keeps failing it is still sending to the channel that the webhook is associated with and it keeps ingorning the channel attribute

my example

```
async sendMsg(msg){
   await this.webhook.send({  
            text : "Message",
            channel : "#CHANNELID"
          }

             }
```

But as i sad it keeps sending message not to the channel i specific it on the post request
How can i achieve this Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Slack webhooks can post **only** to their **designated channels**.

If you want to post to the channel of your choice, you need to upgrade your implementation.

Assign **relevant scopes**(chat:write) to your app,

 and use **slack web methods.**

  e.g. https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage